# How to put advertisement to my android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, ads

I am new to integrating advertisement into my android application.
I don't know how it's going to work with Android Devices and how to integrate it into my Project.
But just because of the requirement, I have to put the advertisement to my project.

I would need details for the following.

- How to add advertisements to my project?
- How is it going to work?
- What steps do I have to follow to integrate it into my project?

It would be best if there is a simple demo project that can explain.